# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process c#

Tags: c#

I have a some code in C# to delete a file, and sometimes I get the following IOException  while I can't find any program using this file.

```
The process cannot access the file  because it is being used by another process
```

How can I solve this problem?

I did not find any solution.

Comment: Please show us your code in order for us to help you further. The error means that something else is using the file so you can't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Process Monitor to look which process is causing the issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon
I bet it's your own code that did something before with the file and didn't really finish it.